# closing parenthesis is not valid input at this position when creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a table on MySQL Workbench, but it's showing the error:

> "()" (closing parenthesis) is not valid input at this position when creating table

On the last closing parenthesis:

```sql
create table generics (
    idGen int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    nameGen nvarchar (255) not null,
    type_id int not null,
    id2 int not null,
    pk int not null,
    active bit not null,
    created_at datetime null,
    updated_at datetime null,
    created_by nvarchar(255) null,
    updated_by nvarchar(255) null,

    constraint primary key(idGen),
    constraint foreign key(type_id)
)
```

I've read that sometimes this happens when having issues when saving as UTF8 with BOM, but this query hasn't been saved yet, also i've never had this issue before, additionally it's my first time working with nvarchar, so idk if it has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

For the Foreign Key constraint, you are missing REFERENCES part.
This key should point to a primary key in another table.

> A FOREIGN KEY in MySQL creates a link between two tables by one specific column of both tables. The specified column in one table must be a PRIMARY KEY and referred by the column of another table known as FOREIGN KEY.

Please check below for refernce

```
create table generics1 (
    type_id int not null,
    constraint primary key(type_id)
    );

create table generics (
    idGen int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    nameGen nvarchar (255) not null,
    type_id int not null,
    id2 int not null,
    pk int not null,
    active bit not null,
    created_at datetime null,
    updated_at datetime null,
    created_by nvarchar(255) null,
    updated_by nvarchar(255) null,

    constraint primary key(idGen),
    constraint foreign key(type_id) REFERENCES generics1(type_id)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing create a table using design view in mysql workbench then export that table as script you will get the way to write a table using script then do the changes in your existing script and this error will go 
Hope this will help